# Angular element supress (change) event from firing under a certain condition

Tags: angular

I have the following two elements in Agnular

```
         <input type="text" (change)="UpdateDetails()"
                [(ngModel)]="name"/>


            <i (click)="name=''; $event.stopPropagation(); "></i>
```

The `<i>` element is styled in a way to show the clear (X) icon on top of the input.  Its purpose it to clear the contents of what the user is typing in.

Consider the following scenario

1. User navigates to the input box and types in something and decides to clear it with the (X) icon.
2. User clicks the (X) icon.  This clears the icon, however since there is a `(change)` event on the input this also triggers the `UpdateDetails` method, which I don't want it to do.

So basically what I'm trying to do is to suppress the `change` event when the user clicks the (x) icon to clear the input text content.

I tried `$event.stopPropagation()` but I don`t think this works in this scenario.

Comment: In two-way data binding I don't think it's possible to stop `change` event. Either you need to check in your `UpdateDetail()` method to return if `name=' '`.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot do that since the change event fires before the (click) event fires on the icon, so I get the newly typed input in the text box. Is there another event which I can tap into?

Comment: try  `(change)="name && UpdateDetails()"`

Comment: I cannot try this as well because the name gets set to empty only after the (change) event has fired

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="text" (input)="name && UpdateDetails()"
            [(ngModel)]="name"/>
```

Or using an auxiliar variable `onclear`

```
<input type="text" (input)="!onclear && UpdateDetails();onclear=false;"
            [(ngModel)]="name"/>

        <i (click)="onclear=true;name='';"></i>
```

NOTE: (change) happens when lost focus, (input) happens any change in input

Comment: the main problem here is that the (click) event fires after the (change) or (input) event.  This is the problem I have been having all along and trying to overcome.

Comment: I make a simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fx9b3b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. If you "click" the icon, the "count" is not increment

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by using **ngModelChange**.

So get the input from the .ts file using **[ngModel]**.

Please refer the following code:

```
<input type="text" #name  (ngModelchange)="UpdateDetails()"
                [ngModel]="name"/>
```

Comment: I honestly don't know how this will solve the problem, I don't think you even read my original question.